fresh install Magento 2.4.6-p6 : localhost text dispaly error and admin page keeps loading, please help
update 20240813
finally solve it at first step.if later found problem I will update.
It's a tiny problem because it seems like that I didn't know docker volume very well.
And I found most installation guide in magento devdoc is not about docker deployment, but only localhost. So if you deploy magento by docker, you'd better not allow by it at all.
update 20240730
I have already tested kinds of version combination of nginx, php, magento2. But the result always shows incorrectly.
Then I found I earlier deleted this in nginx.conf.sample:

If I delete this sentence then the luma theme displays normal with some error in css.

If I use this sentence then the magento2 pages shows 404 not found.

so the question is that:
If I use nginx container and php-fpm container to deploy magento2, is the nginx at first search and match index.php in nginx host but not php-fpm host?  so the pages shows 404?
in my opinion, the sequence is that :

location {} then try_file /index.php

location php {} , search index.php in nginx host and try_file 404

if delete try_file 404, then send index.php request through fastcgi to php-fpm host?


how to solve it?
thank you
=========================
ENV
use docker deploy magento2 by different containers.

magento2 + php-fpm as a container;
nginx as a container;
mysql as a container;

etc.

magento 2.4.6-p6
MacBook apple M1 max macOS Sonoma 14.5
docker desktop: 4.30.0
engine: 26.1.1
docker-compose: 2.27.0
composer:2.2.24
elasticsearch:8.11.4
kibana:8.11.4
mysql:8.0
php:8.2.18-fpm
redis:7.0.15
nginx:1.24.0
dockerfile: 3.8

Background
Hello everybody,
Fresh install Magento 2.4.6-p6
Homepage's text style shows incorrect.And picture shows right.
Admin page keeps logging.
I checked the logs. always shows requirejs-config.js 404 and others 404.
It seems like only requirejs-config.js shows 404 and others js and css works correctly;
Please help.
thank you.
LOG
log for localhost homepage:


2024-07-16 15:32:44 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:32:44 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21139 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:32:44 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:32:44 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js HTTP/1.1" 404 225 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:32:44 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:32:44 +0000] "GET /media/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 360 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:32:44 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:32:44 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 17436 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
logs for admin page:


2024-07-16 15:34:20 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:34:20 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1391 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:34:20 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:34:20 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js HTTP/1.1" 404 225 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:34:20 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:34:20 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21139 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:34:20 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:34:20 +0000] "GET /media/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 360 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2024-07-16 15:34:20 192.168.65.1 - - [16/Jul/2024:07:34:20 +0000] "GET /static/version1721113676/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 17436 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15" "-"

20240717 update file as follows: fix $realpath in Validator.php and app/etc/di.xml.
but seems that has no effect again.



Can please provide the screenshots for frontend seems - url rewrite in not working correctly.

Do the following changes in file - vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php in magento install dir ,
Find -
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

Replace with :
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

Open file app/etc/di.xml in magento install dir, find
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

Replace with
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Now run below command if it's works for you, if you face any issue then let me know.
rm -rf pub/static
rm -rf var
rm -rf generated
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush


thank you for reply. but seems has no effect.

Updated answers please check if its help.

thank you for help again. I have updated the log and seems has no effect yet.
